# In bash scripts, is the brackets notation better than back-quotes?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, brackets

When I learnt to write bash scripts, I put the output of a command in a variable using back-quotes, *e.g.*,

```
ALLPDFS=`find . -name \*.\[pP\]\[dD\]\[fF\]`
```

but most of the 'official' scripts (the ones downloaded in Linux packages *etc*.) use the notation with the dollar sign and brackets:

```
ALLPDFS=$(find . -name \*.\[pP\]\[dD\]\[fF\])
```

Would there be a good reason to choose one over the other? I guess the second is more in line with other bash syntax. For timing though I tried

```
time for (( i=0; i<10; i++ )); do  a=`find . -name \*.\[pP\]\[dD\]\[fF\]`; done
time for (( i=0; i<10; i++ )); do a=$(find . -name \*.\[pP\]\[dD\]\[fF\]); done
```

and it does not make any difference. Is one better for stack/heap usage perhaps?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22709371/backticks-vs-braces-in-bash

Comment: thanks! interesting -- answer to a different question, with different terminology, in the wrong forum...

Comment: See [BashFAQ #82: Why is $(...) preferred over \`...\` (backticks)?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$()` notation is preferred when you need to nest it, i.e. you can write

```
echo $(echo $(echo 123))
```

but the equivalent in ``` `` ``` would be

```
echo `echo \`echo 123 \``
```

Opening and closing parentheses are distinguishable, so there's no need to backslash.

Comment: thanks! yes I think the nesting argument is enough to close the deal.

Comment: @alle_meije Backticks also have some weird effects on other escaped characters inside the backticked command. Essentially, it adds another parse-the-escapes processing step, so escapes (backslashes) inside it have to be doubled. Inside nested backticks, they'd have to be quadrupled. `$( )` avoids all this nonsense.